# Sort month name in HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am a newbie in SQL. I currently have a database with 4 columns: year, month, day, and total money (months are in the string format: Jan, Feb, ...). Furthermore, I am developing the database by using HeidiSQL.

Hence, may I ask that how can I sort the month column in order such as Jan, Feb, ...? I did try SORT BY month, but it seems the database sorted in alphabet.

Please help me, thanks so much.

Comment: "*months are in the string format*" - don't do that. Never ever store dates (or numbers) as character columns. Change your model to use a proper `date` column to store dates and then the sorting will automatically work correctly.

Comment: Best solution is to use a date column but if you can\`t change it use a `CASE WHEN col='Jan' THEN 1`.. etc

Comment: May I ask that I just changed column month with datatype Varchar, then how can I sort the months now? I am thinking about convert month(varchar) to month(int), then sort them, but I have no idea how to do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can convert a short month name to a `datetime` with [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
select str_to_date('Jul', '%b');
```

You can use this to order by:

```
order by
        year
,       str_to_date(month, '%b')
,       day
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e7402/1/0)

Comment: I am sorry but your method is not work. What is '%b' mean? Btw, the month column is in the full format, ie. January, February, ... I am using HeidiSQL and I tried your method but it was not work, although it has the function str_to_date.

Comment: For the full month name, try `%M` instead of `%b`. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) has a full list of format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be independent of internationalization settings for the MySQL server and still search by English month names, you could use `field()`:

```
order by field(monthcol, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
```

I mention this because `%b` in `str_to_date()` is controlled by the locale settings, so it will not always work for English month names.  (The parameter that controls this is `lc_time_names`, described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names).)